# When creating a Sankey Diagram in Python with plotly, I cannot control the order of the links in all cases

Tags: python, plotly, figure

[output of the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLfPN.png)

I defined each link with value 1 so that can give each link a different colour. As you can see in the code, the blue coloured links are all placed in the first 4 rows of the links definition. Although they do not "leave" 'Node A' in the first 4 positions.
Is there any way to bring the blue links all together on top of 'Node A'?
Here you can find an example code of the Issue:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Define the nodes and links data
nodes = ['Node A', 'Node B', 'Node C']
links = [
    {'source': 0, 'target': 1, 'value': 1, 'color': 'blue'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 1, 'value': 1, 'color': 'blue'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'blue'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'blue'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 1, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 1, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 1, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
    {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'value': 1, 'color': 'gray'},
]

# Create a Sankey diagram trace
trace = go.Sankey(
    node=dict(
        label=nodes
    ),
    link=dict(
        source=[link['source'] for link in links],
        target=[link['target'] for link in links],
        value=[link['value'] for link in links],
        color=[link['color'] for link in links],
        line=dict(
            color=[link['color'] for link in links],
            width=0.5
        )
    )
)

# Create the layout
layout = go.Layout(title="Sankey Diagram")

# Create the figure
figure = go.Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout)

# Display the figure
figure.show()
```